# Potential usecase for SeeAllData = true

Tags: seealldata

As current api set default test class with SeeAllData=false and is advisable for us to use sample data,I am wondering what is ideal case for SeeAllData=true.

I am planning to write test class that can be used for common testing for example when we want to deploy any app exchange so we run this test class to check everything is okay.By using SeeAllData=true ,I believe it will increase visibility what can goes wrong during testing.This test class is not use to cover the class(maybe in future) but that is not the purpose currently.

Please let me know if this is not approachable method.

Comment: Check this out. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/149110/when-is-it-appropriate-to-use-seealldata-true

Answer (score 4):

As a generic version of the answer in the [question linked in the comment](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/149110), you should use `SeeAllData=true` when the documentation for a specific feature tells you that you **must** use it, and you should **not** use it otherwise. SeeAllData has no other purpose than letting you access data that is not available during isolation testing.

It will not help you diagnose problems with your unit tests, and in fact is more likely to cause problems than it is to solve them, since production data can mess up your tests (e.g. by introduce unexpected records or values into your tests, or introducing artificial database contention).

Keep in mind that an installed package's code, particularly triggers, will still run during your unit tests, so if they're going to cause problems, they'll likely still do so with SeeAllData=false. The exception to this rule would be if you wanted to test a package's queries against a large data volume (more than 1,000,000 records) to make sure it doesn't run into selectivity exceptions, that would be a valid use case for SeeAllData=true.

The vast majority of the time, using SeeAllData=false and using sample data is the correct method to use. You should avoid writing SeeAllData=true unit tests until you identify specific objects that may fail because of large data volume exceptions, then use targeted unit tests to make sure that the installed packages will function given a large amount of data.