# Unable to access versionData from test class

Tags: apex, unit-test, list, contentversion

I am facing an issue but I don't know what I'm doing wrong. 
I'm writing a test class for a code which has this 2 lines:

```java
public static Blob getPkpass(){
    // more code here...
    List<ContentVersion> archivoLogo = [SELECT id, ContentDocument.Title, VersionData FROM ContentVersion WHERE ContentDocument.Title = 'logo@2x'];
    List<ContentVersion> archivoIcon = [SELECT id, ContentDocument.Title, VersionData FROM ContentVersion WHERE ContentDocument.Title = 'icon@2x'];
    // more code here...
}
```

The code is working fine but in the test class when this method is executed, I get this error in the list:

> List index out of bounds: 0.

The query works perfectly outside the test class. I have also tried with `@TestVisible` but I get the same result

What I'm doing wrong???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing you got is that test class does not see any data in your org. Add this files in **@TestSetup** or add **@isTest(SeeAllData=true)** annotation to your test method. Also note that you cannot use both TestSetup and SeeAllData at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

The issue arises because you haven't inserted test data. I recommend you insert it in `@TestSetup` method of your TestClass. In the very basic case you can do it next way:

```java
@IsTest
public with sharing class TestClass {

    @TestSetup
    static void dataSetup() {
        ContentVersion contentVersion = new ContentVersion();
        contentVersion.PathOnClient = 'test.txt';
        contentVersion.Title = 'Test file';
        contentVersion.VersionData = Blob.valueOf('Test Data');

        insert contentVersion;

        ContentDocument document = [
                SELECT Id
                FROM ContentDocument
        ][0];
        document.Title = 'logo@2x';
        update document;
    }

    // Test methods

}
```

After that, these entities will exist in DB from the test method of your `TestClass`. I would really recommend you to use `@IsTest(SeeAllData=true)` only in [extremely exceptional cases](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/149110/when-is-it-appropriate-to-use-seealldata-true).